# Construct transition probability matrix: repeat toss a coin until two head or two tails consecutively.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Given an experiment:
repeat toss a coin until two head or two tails consecutively.

Example: HTT, THH, HTHH, THTHTT, etc.

Construct transition probability matrix.

I spent many time to think this problem. To construct the transition probability matrix, we must know the states and transition process. But I don't understand how to construct the states and transition in this problem. Can anyone explain how to construct the state on this problem?
What the transition process on this problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  There are infinitely many states if you keep track of the full history, so doing it that way would give you an infinitely large matrix.  A pretty simple infinite matrix mind you, but infinite all the same.  Is that what you want?  Otherwise you might note that all you really care about is the prior toss.  That simplifies the state space considerably.  But you need to clarify your goals.

Comment: You could reduce the states to (a) start, (b) last toss H but preceding not H, (c) last two tosses HH, (d) last toss T but preceding not T, (e) last two tosses TT.

Comment: @lulu "Otherwise you might note that all you really care about is the prior toss. That simplifies the state space considerably" -> This is what I want.

Comment: Are you sure?  If so, then start by enumerating the relevant states (there really aren't very many of them).

Comment: @lulu So, we can construct the states as Henry's comment?

Comment: Absolutely. $\quad$

Comment: @Henry
Let 0: start;  1: last toss H but preceding not H, 2: last two tosses HH, 3: last toss T but preceding not T, 4: last two tosses TT.
I confused to calculate the transition probability matrix.
Suppose I want to calculate $P_{12}$.

Comment: $P_{12}$ is the transition probability from "last toss H but preceding not H " to "last two tosses HH".
So, the possibilities are "THH, HTHH, THTHH, HTHTHH, ...". How to compute this probability? I'm confused because there are infinite possibilites.

Comment: The probability of going from "last toss H but preceding not H" to "last two tosses HH" in one step is the probability of tossing H, which is $\frac12$ if you have a fair coin

Comment: @Henry Now I confused to determine the probability one step from "start" to other states. 
Does the probability from "start" to "start" is $0$? I think if we start from $H$ then in one step, we must get $HH$ or $HT$, so impossible to get only $H$.

Comment: @Henry I confused for the probability one step from "start" to "last toss H but preceding not H". I confused the probability is among $0$ or $\frac{1}{2}$. If start from H, then in one step we must get HH or HT , so the probability is $0$. But if start from T, then in one step we must get TH or TT so the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.